# UIPrerenderedIcon glossy problem

Tags: iphone, xcode, icons

i have a problem. When I want to undo the glossy stile of the App Icon, the Apple Documentation http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW1 says, that there is a UIKit Key for that.

I tried to find this Key (UIPrerenderedIcon) in the Info.plist file of my Application, but I couldn't find it anywhere.

I use XCode 3.2.1 and iOS 3.0.

I guess that this key can only be used in an higher SDK, am I right?

Thank you in advanced for your response

Nikolay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that key is available on all OS so you must be able to set it. In editor that key is named "Icon already includes gloss effects" - try finding it.

P.S. If I remember correctly Apple requires newly submitted apps to be built with sdk version at least 4.0 and it is generally a good idea to use the latest sdk version to build you app

Answer (score 20):

If you are having this problem in iOS 5, as per [Alex Stone's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8410769/296446), you have too edit the plist it in **2** places.

[image: Remove Icon Gloss]

Answer (score 2):

For those using Xcode 4.2 or later, it will add this key automatically within the 'Icon files' group when you add a new icon. To fix, simply remove the key you added, expand the 'Icon files' group and set the flag to YES in there instead.