# How to disable all icon effects, including gloss effect, on iphone/ipad for my application?

Tags: iphone, ios, icons

How to disable all icon effects, including gloss effect, on iphone/ipad for my application? Both on old iOS and on iOS 5.

**UPDATED:**

Should I add set property `UIPrerenderedIcon` **two times** - for old iOS and for iOS 5 as the child of iOS 5 tree?

[image]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please be more specific. What icon effects do you mean?

Comment: [The answer you seek is in this duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003177/how-to-disable-highlighting-of-the-app-icon).

Comment: Already answered on stackoverflow : [removing-shine-gloss-effect-on-the-iphone-through-uiprerenderedicon-not-working][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958920/removing-shine-gloss-effect-on-the-iphone-through-uiprerenderedicon-not-working

Comment: Please view the question again.

Comment: It's not duplicate - please look again to the question. And different text in the same question is very useful.

Comment: That image is the best answer, you have to set the "Icon already includes gloss effects" to YES in two places. Once within the Icon Files (iOS 5) -> Primary Icon directory as well as the outside plist directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

go in plist file and and click on + sign then search for,

Icon already includes gloss effects = YES;

Comment: Hey, anybody... What's about using this property as child of iOS 5 tree?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another "Icon already includes gloss effects = YES" under "Icon Files (iOS 5)/Primary Icon"