# How to remove iphone icon gloss effect? (in FLASH CS5.5)

Tags: iphone, flash, air, icons

I changed the code `![CDATA[<key>UIDeviceFamily</key><array><string>2</string></array>]]`   with `![CDATA[ <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key><true/><array><string>2</string></array>]]`                                 but it didn't work.  Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Why did you include FLASH CS5 in your title?

Anyway, question has been answered before here:

[Removing Shine/Gloss effect on the iPhone through UIPrerenderedIcon not working on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958920/removing-shine-gloss-effect-on-the-iphone-through-uiprerenderedicon-not-working)

This shows how to make it apply to emulator and iOS 5 hardware.

Specifically,

`

```
<key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
    <array>
        <string>Icon.png</string>
        <string>Icon@2x.png</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful if you wrote *where* did you change that line. However it seems a fragment of an Info.plist and as such, your changed line has an invalid format. Try something like this:

```
<key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
<true/>
<key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
<array><string>2</string></array>
```

Also check out if you have the prerendered icon value set in "Icon files (iOS5)" dictionary as described in [Removing Shine/Gloss effect on the iPhone through UIPrerenderedIcon not working on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958920/removing-shine-gloss-effect-on-the-iphone-through-uiprerenderedicon-not-working/8410769#8410769)